# How can % 8 actually return 8?

Tags: javascript, modulus

I have this function for custom padding, which works like this:

```
    var length = 8 - ( (this.buffer.length - 1 + this.buffer.length - 39) % 8);
    var padding = Buffer.alloc(length + 1);
    for (i = 1; i <= length; i++) {
        padding.writeUInt8(i, i-1);
    }
    padding.writeUInt8(length, length);
    this.buffer = Buffer.concat([this.buffer, padding]);
```

where this.buffer may have variable length. (always > 0)
However, how can there be a number which lets length be 8?
Since I'm doing 8 - x % 8, I'm expecting values between 0 and 7, or am I not?

Comment: 8 - x % 8 --> (8 - x) % 8

Comment: `8 % 8// 0` - if you subtract that from 8, you get 8

Comment: `%` has precedence over `-`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x %8` varies from 0 to 7.

`8 - x%8` varies from `8-0 == 8` to `8-7 == 1`.

Comment: Oh.
I'm facepalming so hard right now.

Thanks everyone!